# while Loop summation (in python)

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook

I'm creating a function (using python) to automatically buy and sell a crypto, and automatically calculate the cumulative profit after each trade was done. I also want to see the profit for each trade in a list, this is how my function looks so far:

```
def tradingstrat(symbol, open_position = False):
    total = 0
    trade = []
    while True: 
        #pulling data all the time because of the loop
        df = getminutedata(symbol)
        
        #check whether we have an opening position
        if not open_position:
            buyprice = df.Close[-1]
            qty = money/buyprice
            print('Bought', qty,"amount of", symbol,"@",buyprice)
            open_position = True  
            break
          
    if open_position:
        while True:   
            #pulling data all the time because of the loop
            df = getminutedata(symbol)
            sellprice = df.Close[-1]
            profit = (sellprice-buyprice)*qty                           
            print('Sell', qty,"amount of", symbol,"@",sellprice)
            open_position = False
            
            break
            
        total += profit
        trade.append(profit)
        
        print(trade)
        print("Cummulative profit:",total)
```

With this, somehow the profit and cumulative profit always show the same value (as if the cumulative profit value is being reset after each loop), and the profit for each trade is also not appended to the list.

I wonder where did I do wrong? thank you!

Comment: `if open_position:` will always be true, because you only break out of the first loop when you assign `open_position = True`.

Comment: `total += profit` and `trade.append(profit)` aren't in the loop.

Comment: If you call the function with `open_position = True`, you'll never get out of the first loop.

Comment: You have an unconditional `break` statement in the second `while` loop, so it never repeats. What's the point of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def tradingstrat(symbol, open_position = False):
    total = 0
    trade = []

    #check whether we have an opening position
    if not open_position:
        df = getminutedata(symbol)
        buyprice = df.Close[-1]
        qty = money/buyprice
        print('Bought', qty,"amount of", symbol,"@",buyprice)

    else:
        df = getminutedata(symbol)
        sellprice = df.Close[-1]
        profit = (sellprice-buyprice)*qty                           
        print('Sell', qty,"amount of", symbol,"@",sellprice)
        total += profit
        trade.append(profit)
        
    print(trade)
    print("Cumulative profit:",total)
```

I removed your `while` loops as you immediately break out of them. I also moved the `total += profit` and `trade.append(profit)` inside the loops so they will be updated. Some code reformatting was done as well